# Cannot select text with OrbitControls?

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, textselection

I'm making a Three.js project with OrbitControls.js but i realize that i cannot select (highlight) any text with OrbitControls.

Here the example link: http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit 
(try select text "orbit control example" on the top of example, we can't do that)

So, How to select (highlight)  text  with OrbitControl?

(or i have to disable control everytime i want to copy text ?)

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What text are you trying to select?

Comment: Hi, i edited, i want user can select and copy any text on my project

Comment: Do you mean the html-text or any html text or what are you talking about? 3D Text geometry in your scene?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, [`OrbitControls`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) listens to mouse events on `document`, and this is why you cannot use the mouse in the same page for other purposes such as selecting text or opening the context menu.  You can change this behavior by specifying a DOM node as the second argument to constructor `THREE.OrbitControls`.  Then `OrbitControls` listens to mouse events on this DOM node instead of the whole `document`.

If you have the code like

```
var renderer = …;
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
…
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
```

then replace the last line with

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

In the case of [the example you mentioned](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit), you can move the initialization of `controls`:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

after the initialization of `renderer`, and add `renderer.domElement` as the second argument to the constructor `THREE.OrbitControls`.  Now you can select the text on the page.

Comment: I love you!! Made my day so much

Comment: You came in, took one shut and took it down. This is how a veteran codes.
Good job mate!

Answer (score 1):

Create the input:

```
var identidad = document.createElement( 'INPUT' );
```

Extend the click event by giving the focus to this element:

```
identidad.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
    $(this).focus();
});
```